# Static Files that contain Linux Kernal Version Information

Tags: kernel, version

I am looking for a list of files (which can be viewed on a dead box system, i.e. they have to be filesystem artifacts) which contain information on the kernel version the system is running.

My use case is that I am analyzing a bunch of embedded linux firmware images and I would like to pull out the kernel version.

Surprisingly, finding information on this sort of artifact was difficult - most resources online list various commands you can run (uname -r, hostnamectl, etc.), but not static files where this datapoint may exist. /proc/version appears to be one location, however unfortunately the /proc directory does not seem to exist in any of the images I have looked at thus far.

Essentially I am looking for a list of all files where kernel version information may exist on a linux system. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No /proc, really? Probably compiled with `CONFIG_PROC_FS=n`. I wonder what's the rationale for this.

Comment: Well, there are a handful where that directory does exist, but it generally appears to be empty. Not sure if that is populated when the system is booted or what. Again, I am looking purely at offline images. I have plans to do emulation later for some of the harder-to-get artifacts but I figured kernel version is something that would likely exist statically on the filesystem as well. Most of the images are using squashfs, for what its worth.

Comment: `Not sure if that is populated when the system is booted or what.` - it's a virtual filesystem stored in RAM managed by kernel, it's continuously upgraded to reflect the state of the system. `Again, I am looking purely at offline images.` - what do you mean by *offline*? You mean not connected to the internet? /proc has nothing to do with network connection.

Comment: Sorry, using the word "offline" loosely there - I mean non-running systems or images. These are all embedded firmware images with very small file systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine which file in the data you have contains the kernel that was used, you can extract the version from that. In some cases, `file` can extract the version:

```sh
file /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-16-amd64
/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-16-amd64: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 4.19.0-16-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19), RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x5, Normal VGA
```

In other cases, you’ll need to look for the version yourself:

```
$ grep -a "Linux version" /boot/pine64/Image
Linux version 3.10.105 (debian@pine64) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian/Linaro 4.9.2-10) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 20 17:02:37 CEST 2017
```

This is the most reliable artifact you can use on an inert file system.

Answer (score 0):

> on a dead box system ... unfortunately the /proc directory does not seem to exist

Of course it is not going to exist. The /proc directory is populated in RAM at run time by the runnung kernel. So just find the kernel image(s) and examile it directly with the `file` command, or with `strings`, or whathave you. See if there's a /boot directory on that disk -- you may find the kernel(s) there.

Edit: Oops! Didn't notice that Stephen Kitt already answered this. :-)